# Intersection of two lists in Python

Tags: python, array, complexity

I am currently working on an algorithm, which involves finding the intersection of two lists. That is, given the following inputs `[1,2,2,1]`,`[2,2]` the result would be `[2,2]`.

I have implemented it in two ways which hopefully should be easy to understand

**Method 1**

```
def intersect(nums1, nums2):
    dict_count = {}
    for num1 in nums1:
        if num1 not in dict_count:
            dict_count[num1] = 1
        else:
            dict_count[num1] += 1

    inter_arr = []

    for num2 in nums2:
        if num2 in dict_count and dict_count[num2] > 0:
            inter_arr.append(num2)
            dict_count[num2] -= 1

    return inter_arr
```

**Method 2**

```
def intersect_v2(nums1, nums2):
    arr_one = sorted(nums1)
    arr_two = sorted(nums2)

    p1, p2 = 0, 0
    inter_arr = []

    while p1 < len(arr_one) and p2 < len(arr_two):
        if arr_one[p1] < arr_two[p2]:
            p1 += 1
        elif arr_one[p1] > arr_two[p2]:
            p2 += 1
        else:
            inter_arr.append(arr_one[p1])
            p1 += 1
            p2 += 1

    return inter_arr
```

I have two questions about time complexity:

- What if nums1's size is small compared to nums2's size? Which algorithm is better? (The original algorithm problem is from Leetcode and this is a follow up question to the problem)

It feels like the pointer method always win, but I can't articulate why.

- If the inputs always came in sorted, which algorithm would be more efficient with respect to time and space? (This would mean that first two lines to `intersect_v2` would not be needed)

From my understanding `intersect` would be O(M+N) since you would have to iterate through the two arrays not matter what. The second one is a bit confusing since it feels like the it would be `O(Z)` where Z is less than Max(M,N) and greater than Min(M,N), is that about right?

Comment: What are the requirements on the order of the elements in the output? (If there are no requirements on the order, then `(Counter(a) & Counter(b)).elements()` solves the problem.)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40527584/what-is-the-fastest-algorithm-for-intersection-of-two-sorted-lists

And here a Python implementation of the accepted answer: https://gist.github.com/fjsj/9c9f7f36cfd3205343e333d86778433c

Answer (score 2):

Blockquote

> - What if nums1's size is small compared to nums2's size? Which
>   algorithm is better? (The original algorithm problem is from Leetcode
>   and this is a follow up question to the problem)
>
> It feels like the pointer method always win, but I can't articulate why.

Granted, in many cases, the pointer method might be faster because it might break out of the `while` after exhausting the elements of the smaller list without having to consider the vast majority of the elements of the larger list.

However, think of a pathological worst case where `max(nums1) > max(nums2)` such as `nums1 = [1_000_000]` and `nums2 = list(range(100_000))`. The pointer approach as shown would have to examine all `100_000` elements of `nums2`.

What are some ways you can mitigate this?

Taking advantage of the fact that `nums1` and `nums2` are sorted, you can get the `min` and `max` of each list in `O(1)` and use those values as additional conditions to break out of the `while` loop earlier.

Given that the input is sorted, binary search might speed things up considerably. [`bisect.bisect_left`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html#bisect.bisect_left) is python's own implementation of binary search. Given that sorted input, binary search would allow you to potentially skip over larges swaths of the input as follows:

```
while p1 < len(nums1) and p2 < len(nums2):
    if nums1[p1] < nums2[p2]:
        # advance p1 to an index s.t. nums1[p1] >= nums2[p2]
        p1 = bisect.bisect_left(nums1, nums2[p2])
    elif nums1[p1] > nums2[p2]:
        # advance p2 to an index s.t. nums2[p2] >= nums1[p1]
        p2 = bisect.bisect_left(nums2, nums1[p1])
    else:
        inter_arr.append(arr_one[p1])
        p1 += 1
        p2 += 1
```

---

P.S.:
`bisect_left` has two optional keyword arguments, `lo` and `hi` which might be useful here as well.

Comment: I believe `min()` and `max()` are O(n), not O(1).  But they run at "C" speed, not Python speed.

Comment: In general, yes, but I think we were assuming the input was sorted to begin with, in which case, `min` and `max` can be found in `O(1)` as `nums[0]` and `nums[-1]` respectively.